# Receiving data from a form and modificating it using preg_replace

Tags: forms, preg-replace

I have the following HTML code:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
    <b>Name: <input type="text" name="username" size="20" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" />
    </form>
```

and:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $check = $_POST['username'];
    ?>
```

Whenever a user submits his username, the user should receive his username back but with the following modifications:

1) *Sapce bars will be replaced with "_"

2) *All letters will become non-capital letters.

Example:
Username: "I Like Icecream"

Result:
i_like_icecream

The message should be displayed to the user as an variable through an echo.

```
    echo "$result";
```

I was thinking about doing it with preg_repalce, but didn't really manage to since I am not familiar with it very well. Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace() is way too powerful but way expensive for this task. The patterns you need to change are constant, so you're better of using str_replace() and mb_strtolower()

```
$encoding = 'UTF-8';                     // optional
$name = $_POST['usernamename']         
$name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);  
$name = mb_strtolower($name, $encoding); // or $name = mb_strtolower($name); if you don't specify encoding
```

Comment: @user1938653 you're welcome. Could you mark my answer as the chosen one then?